# Trying to add a certain value as a key and multiple values for that key from a html table python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm using beautifulsoup and python to get the headers of each table in the html page as well as the multiple 'a' tag values for each of those tables. I want to add each of the headers that I get as a key value for a dictionary and each of the 'a' tag values (the links) as values for that key, whether there are 1,2,3 etc. links in that table. Right now, I have a list of headers and links, but I can't add multiple links for one index in that list so I am only adding one link to the list when there are multiple links in one table .I am able to get the headers and add them as keys to a dictionary, but I am struggling to get each of the links in the table and add them to that key. So, the output of the dictionary would look like {'header1': [url, url, url], 'header2': [url, url], 'header3': [url, url, url], "}. Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

s = soup(open('april12016.html').read(), 'lxml')

headers = []
links = []
head = {}

for table in s.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'affected_software'}):
    headers.append(table.select('b')[0].text)
    for a in table.find_all('a'):
        links.append(a.get('href'))

keys = range(len(headers))
for i in keys:
    for x in headers:
        head[i] = x
```

Here is some of the HTML source code

```html
<!-- Affected software tables -->
  </table>    <table class="affected_software" border=1 cellpadding=0 width="99%">
    <thead style="background-color: #ededed">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><b>Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>CVE ID</b></td>
            <td><b>KB Article</b></td>
            <td><b>Restart Required</b></td>
            <td><b>Severity</b></td>
            <td><b>Impact</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0154</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Critical<br></td>
     <td>Remote Code Execution<br></td>
</tr>    <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0160</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Important<br></td>
     <td>Remote Code Execution<br></td>
</tr>    <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0162</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=4015219; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015219; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=4015219; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015219; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Moderate<br></td>
     <td>Information Disclosure<br></td>
</tr>    <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0166</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=3147458; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3147458; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Critical<br></td>
     <td>Remote Code Execution<br></td>
</tr>
</table>    <table class="affected_software" border=1 cellpadding=0 width="99%">
    <thead style="background-color: #ededed">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><b>Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 for 32-bit Systems Service Pack 1</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>CVE ID</b></td>
            <td><b>KB Article</b></td>
            <td><b>Restart Required</b></td>
            <td><b>Severity</b></td>
            <td><b>Impact</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0154</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=3148198; URL=https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=742fffb3-232c-4082-b054-853b6ad48406; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=3148198; URL=https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=742fffb3-232c-4082-b054-853b6ad48406; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Critical<br></td>
     <td>Remote Code Execution<br></td>
</tr>    <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0162</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=4015549; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549; SubType=Monthly Rollup}">@{ID=4015549; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549; SubType=Monthly Rollup}</a><br><br /><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=4014661; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4014661; SubType=IE Cumulative}">@{ID=4014661; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4014661; SubType=IE Cumulative}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br><br />Yes<br></td>
     <td>Moderate<br></td>
     <td>Information Disclosure<br></td>
</tr>
</table>    <table class="affected_software" border=1 cellpadding=0 width="99%">
    <thead style="background-color: #ededed">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><b>Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 for x64-based Systems Service Pack 1</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>CVE ID</b></td>
            <td><b>KB Article</b></td>
            <td><b>Restart Required</b></td>
            <td><b>Severity</b></td>
            <td><b>Impact</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0154</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=3148198; URL=https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=84b9ce93-9123-4f06-8ae1-fcb221a41938; SubType=Security Update}">@{ID=3148198; URL=https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=84b9ce93-9123-4f06-8ae1-fcb221a41938; SubType=Security Update}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br></td>
     <td>Critical<br></td>
     <td>Remote Code Execution<br></td>
</tr>    <tr>
     <td>CVE-2016-0162</td>
     <td><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=4015549; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549; SubType=Monthly Rollup}">@{ID=4015549; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549; SubType=Monthly Rollup}</a><br><br /><a href="https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=@{ID=4014661; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4014661; SubType=IE Cumulative}">@{ID=4014661; URL=https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4014661; SubType=IE Cumulative}</a><br></td>
     <td>Yes<br><br />Yes<br></td>
     <td>Moderate<br></td>
     <td>Information Disclosure<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please include the source code of the HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

s = soup(open('april12016.html').read(), 'lxml')

links = []
head = {}

for table in s.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'affected_software'}):
   heading = table.select('b')[0].text
   links = []
   for a in table.find_all('a'):
       links.append(a.get('href')) # get all the links
   head[heading] = links # put it in a dictionay
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Is there a reason that this adds all the links compared to my code which only added one link?

Comment: Your `links` list would have all the links correctly. You're not using that list for your `head` dictionary though, so unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Updated, please try like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('april12013.html'), "html.parser")

headers = {}
for table in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'affected_software'}):
    for a in table.find_all('a'):
        headers.setdefault(table.select('b')[0].text,[]).append(a.get('href'))
```

Comment: When I try this, I am getting the first table header followed by every single link in each of the tables. What I want is only the links located in that first table so the first location in the dictionary has the first header, followed by the links in that first table